# How to prevent 'postcss-preset-env' from removing CSS logical properties?

Tags: css, webpack, postcss

When using the following in my Webpack config:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/i,
  use: [
    'style-loader',
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: { importLoaders: 1 },
    },
    {
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: {
        postcssOptions: {
          plugins: [
            [
              'postcss-preset-env'
            ],
          ],
        },
      },
    },
    "sass-loader"
  ],
},
```

I'm noticing that sometimes CSS rules like the following are removed from the bundled CSS output.

```
img {
  margin-inline-end: 1rem;
}
```

When removing the above Webpack config, the rule above is applied as expected.

More specifically:

- when an `[dir="rtl"]` attribute is set on the `html` element, the `margin-inline-end: 1rem;` style exists
- when the `dir` attribute is not set, the `margin-inline-end: 1rem;` style does not exist in the bundled output
- when the `'postcss-preset-env'` plugin is removed, the `margin-inline-end: 1rem;` style exists regardless of the presence of the `[dir]` attribute

What is causing this behavior and how can I disable it while continuing to use `postcss-preset-env` for other things like `autoprefixer`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `postcss-preset-env` is processing stage 2+ rules, depending on the exact version of `cssdb` was installed, you might need to tweak the `stage` option while using `postcss-preset-env` to a higher value like `stage: 3`.

And looks like some logical properties like `margin-inline-end` will be processed into

```css
[dir='ltr'] { margin-right: 1rem } ...
```

Also rules can also be disabled precisely in the option :

```
{
  /* use stage 2 features + disable logical properties and values rule */
  stage: 2,
  features: {
    'logical-properties-and-values': false
  }
}
```

This github repo [vanilla-js-prototype-starter](https://github.com/gnehcwu/vanilla-js-prototype-starter) has `webpack` & `PostCSS` configured working well, check and see if it can help a bit.

Comment: Amazing, changing Nuxt default stage from 2 to 3 allowed to include CSS logical properties in the final bundled CSS. Thanks!