# Next JS Build Swiper JS Issue with Tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs, build, next.js, tailwind-css, swiper.js

I set a project with NextJS, Tailwind CSS and Swiper JS.

When I run Yarn Dev I can successfully display my Swiper Slider without any error

[image]

However, once I built the project and run Start I am facing a broken slider with no navigation but I can still swipe but I get a blank

[image]

To reproduce just set a NextJS project with Tailwind config and Swiper slider. Create a file in pages folder with this samples code

```js
// import Swiper core and required modules
import SwiperCore, { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y } from 'swiper'
import Layout from '@modules/Layout'

import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react'

// install Swiper modules
SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y])

const Slider = () => {
  return (
      <div className='container'>
        <Swiper
          spaceBetween={50}
          slidesPerView={1}
          navigation
          pagination={{ clickable: true }}
          onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
          onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
        >
          <SwiperSlide>
            <div className='h-96 w-50 bg-red'>Slide 1</div>
          </SwiperSlide>
          <SwiperSlide>
            <div className='h-96 w-50 bg-blue'>Slide 2</div>
          </SwiperSlide>
          <SwiperSlide>
            <div className='h-96 w-50 bg-orange'>Slide 3</div>
          </SwiperSlide>
          <SwiperSlide>
            <div className='h-96 w-50 bg-green'>Slide 4</div>
          </SwiperSlide>
        </Swiper>
      </div>
  )
}

export default Slider
```

- Swiper Version: 6.5.6.
- Platform/Target and Browser Versions:   CHROME

Comment: How are you using the swiper styles? Are you including the bundled CSS file somewhere, or using their SCSS/Less styles?

Comment: I faced the similar problem and it turns out that removing `postcss-preset-env` in `postcss.config.js` helps me to retain the css in build. Maybe you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64565180/how-to-prevent-postcss-preset-env-from-removing-css-logical-properties)

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue with OP and was able to reproduce the issue using the code OP provided, not only in prod build but also in dev environment for some reason. In the end I was able to solve the issue by:

```js
// Didn't use these imports
// import 'swiper/css'; // core Swiper
// import 'swiper/css/navigation'; // Navigation module
// import 'swiper/css/pagination'; // Pagination module

// Used this bundled instead - it seems to have included navigation, pagination, etc.
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css'
```

My environment:

```
"next": "13.1.6",
"tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
"swiper": "^9.0.1",
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and fixed it with cdn import of css in the head html element and using swiper/react to import
I am using react with nextjs and typescript and tailwind

> In appropriate place- I put in the _document.jsx

```
       <Head>
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css"
          />          
        </Head>
```

> Usage of `<Swiper> and <SwiperSlide>`

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';

// import Swiper core and required modules
import SwiperCore, { Pagination, Navigation } from 'swiper';

// install Swiper modules
SwiperCore.use([Pagination, Navigation]);
```

Comment: Thank you, I use the cdn as my temporary solution for now until I figure out what is happening. And I think you can leave out the css imports and it will still work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the temporary solution. Nothing had worked so far. I was using @wordpress/scripts package with tailwind v3. i could not understand why css was not being imported. I guess this Treeshaking thing can be the reason. Your solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the very same problem using react-swiper with NextJS. I assume the issue is caused by some tree shaking at bundling time that excludes swiper components CSS files since they are not imported in the swiper module (very "random" guessing here since my knowledge on Webpack tree shaking is very basic).

However, I solved the problem by importing swiper .less files into a custom .less file in my project (so they are bundled and minified at build time), then importing the latest .less file into my component file.

Following a code sample

```
/* custom-swiper.less */
@import "~swiper/swiper.less";
@import "~swiper/components/navigation/navigation.less";
@import "~swiper/components/pagination/pagination.less";

/*
 * my swiper style overrides below
 */
...
```