# Overlapping "No files chosen" label in bootstrap form control

Tags: html, css, webpack, bootstrap-5

We recently switched to webpack for our assets (js, scss, ...) and everything went fine so far, except a small bug where the input label behind the file-selector-button overflows with is neighbour as you can see in these examples below. Even with the default bootstrap styles (no additional whatsoever) we still encounter this bug.

[image: Overlapping no file chosen example]
[image: Second example no file chosen]

Basic webpack application configuration:

```js
import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
import "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css"

// [...]

import "bootstrap";
```

Snippet of the first example:

```html
<div class="row pb-3">
  <div class="col">
      <input class="form-control" type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Please select a file
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The second example is from [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/form-control/#file-input)

Even the inspector from e.g. Google Chrome does not help either and by now i could not find any solutions to fix this issue.

I am using Bootstrap 5.2.0 (tested 5.2.2, 5.1.x, ... with same results), no additional changes made to bootstrap itself.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, looks like it has something to do with postcss-loader. Arguments like margin-inline-starts will be "removed" from built version (other Post: [How to prevent 'postcss-preset-env' from removing CSS logical properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64565180/how-to-prevent-postcss-preset-env-from-removing-css-logical-properties))

The suggested solution does not work but removing postcss-loader at all is a possible temporary solution right now... but i will look forward to fix it and keep using postcss-loader

Comment: Adding the proposed solution in the linked post to postcssPresetEnv() inside plugins in postcss.config.js seems to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the solution to the linked question: [How to prevent 'postcss-preset-env' from removing CSS logical properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64565180/how-to-prevent-postcss-preset-env-from-removing-css-logical-properties), add:

```
{
   stage: 2,
   features: {
       'logical-properties-and-values': false
   }
}
```

to `postcssPresetEnv()` inside `postcss.config.js`

The final file should look something like:

```
const postcssPresetEnv = require("postcss-preset-env");

module.exports = {
    plugins: [postcssPresetEnv({
        stage: 2,
        features: {
            'logical-properties-and-values': false
        }
    })],
};
```